# how to remove the slash when reading a table using bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, datatable, python-requests

I am trying to extract a column from a table, however instead of just the the text I also get an (/) after each text. How can I remove this Slash.

```
 def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text)  
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:   
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text   
        tickers.append(ticker)
        
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:   
        pickle.dump(tickers,f)
        
    print(tickers)
    
    return tickers

save_sp500_tickers()
```

this is my out put

```
'WELL\n',
 'WST\n',
 'WDC\n',
 'WU\n',
```

Comment: it is not slash but `\n` which means `new line` which you can remove using `strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces as follows:

```
ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text.strip()
```